# listings package: Automatically invoke preferred style for given language (sclang-prettifier)

Tags: listings

## Problem description

I am looking for a way to make the `listings` package automatically apply my preferred style to a given language, without me having to manually set it via `\lstset{style=...}`.

Specifically, I am using the `sclang-prettifier` package to typeset SuperCollider code, and I would like to automatically invoke its `SuperCollider-IDE` style whenever I introduce a code example using the package's `SuperCollider` language definition.

The long-term objective is to be able to typeset multiple programming languages in the same document, without having to specify both, language and style for each code example. That's why `\lstset` won't work for me.

## Minimal (non-)working example

Save the following example to `main.tex` and compile with `pdflatex main` or `lualatex main`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{listings}%

% 'sclang-prettifier' package defines 'SuperCollider' language
% and 'SuperCollider-IDE' style for 'listings' package
\usepackage{sclang-prettifier}%

% HACK! Define new 'sc' language to couple
% 'SuperCollider-IDE' style to 'SuperCollider' language
\lstdefinelanguage{sc}{%
  style=SuperCollider-IDE,%
}%


\begin{document}


\section{Automatically use preferred style with given language (does not work)}

% NOTE: 'SuperCollider' language defined by \usepackage{sclang-prettifier}

I'd like to \emph{automatically} apply the \verb|SuperCollider-IDE| style to any
code listing that uses \verb|language=SuperCollider|. Currently this does not work,
which is why the following listing will \emph{not} be colored: 

\begin{lstlisting}[language=SuperCollider]
  { SinOsc.ar(440, 0, 0.5) }.play;  // Comment
\end{lstlisting}


\section{Define new language to automatically set style (works partially)}

One idea I had was to define a new language \verb|sc|, which sets the \verb|SuperCollider-IDE|
style, and which I could use to replace the \verb|SuperCollider| language definition.
However, while this colors comments in red as expected, UGens such as \verb|SinOsc| remain black.

\begin{lstlisting}[language=sc]
  { SinOsc.ar(440, 0, 0.5) }.play;  // Comment
\end{lstlisting}


\section{Workaround: Manually define style (inconvenient)}

The only solution that colors both, comments and UGens, as expected is to manually define the
\verb|SuperCollider-IDE| style. However, I'd like to avoid having to do this and would instead
like to \emph{automatically} use the \verb|SuperCollider-IDE| style with the \verb|SuperCollider|
language. 

\lstset{style=SuperCollider-IDE}
\begin{lstlisting}[language=SuperCollider]
  { SinOsc.ar(440, 0, 0.5) }.play;  // Comment
\end{lstlisting}


\end{document}
```

Comment: It would be great if someone with sufficient reputation could create a `sclang-prettifier` tag and add it to this question.